# Как закрепить свою программу в панель задач?

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне нужно, чтобы мое приложение было предназначено для панели задач. То есть открывается ни окно, а просто происходит запуск или при нажатие ПКМ вылазил список, что открыть по программе. Как сделать, чтобы программа была закреплена в панели задач?

Comment: О какой именно версии Windows речь? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35883657/12888024

Comment: Может вам вообще запуск не нужен, а нужна штатная фича windows "Закрепить на панели задач"?

Comment: @aepot Версии 10 и 11

Comment: @АндрейNOP мне нужно, чтобы при запуске в первый раз, она закрепилась в панели задач.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57160775/6766879